# How can I update a value from dropdown without refreshing the page

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to update my value in dropdown without refreshing the page. How can I do this? My code:

```
<div class="dropdown" uib-dropdown>
     <button  type="button" uib-dropdown-toggle class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
    {{ '{{ item.type}}' }}  
     <span class="caret"></span>
     </button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu >
       <li><a ng-show=" item.type != 'food'" ng-click="setRole(item.id, 'food');">food</a></li>
       <li><a ng-show="item.type != 'product'" ng-click="setRole(item.id, 'product')">product</a></li>
       <li><a ng-show="item.type != 'tool'" ng-click="setRole(item.id, 'tool')">tool</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>


 $scope.setRole = function(id, role) {
     ItemService.setType(id, role);
     $scope.getItems($scope.thisPage);
 };
```

So after I choose a value from the dropdown, only if I refresh the page the value  `{{'{{ item.type}}'}}`  is updated. How can I do to update after I choose the value?

Comment: What is happening inside $scope.setRole()? Can you post the code for the service?

Comment: @Vivz you mean the code for setType? Because I already put the code for $scope.setRole()

Comment: I can't see you changing the value of item.type  inside  $scope.setRole()

Comment: Plunker please...

Comment: @Vivz the code is in symfony for changing the role.

Comment: Try putting a $scope.$apply() after you update the value of the variable in symphony, maybe after scope.getItems($scope.thisPage);

Comment: I tried this but no success.

Comment: could you provide the entire controller, the section you post, doesnt help much cause we dont know what itemservice.settype does and also what getItems does. plz